# AS3: Exit full screen event listener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

How to add an event listener that listens to the exit full screen event by pressing escape key ??

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, backtoresize)  //doesn't work :(
```

Thanks :)

Comment: This might be different between mobile platforms. Please clarify what's the target.

Comment: Adobe AIR 3.8 for desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, etc ...)
This triggers whether you enter or leave fullscreen.

Comment: YOU ARE KIDDING ME! :D
I've known of this event listener forever but never thought it works both ways!
Thanks a lot! It works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 2):

I had it like this.

```
mcVideoControls.btnFullscreen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullscreenClicked);



function fullscreenClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
                //fullscreen works only with an internet browser
                if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL) {
                    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
                } 
                else {
                    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
                }
            }
```

But you could rewrite it. It would then be something like this.... wait hang on...

```
package {
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class UserInputHandler{  
        //escape button var
        public static var keyEscape:Boolean;

        public function UserInputHandler(stage:Stage){
            //this events are sending the value true when specific keyboard button is pressed to the stage.
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
        }
        //you can provide more key codes in the function
        private function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{  
            switch(e.keyCode){
                case Keyboard.ESCAPE:
                    UserInputHandler.keyEscape = true;
                    break;

            }
        }
        //function when key is released from pressing
        private function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            switch(e.keyCode){
                case Keyboard.ESCAPE:
                    keyEscape = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work great if I was in need of a toggle key or function, but actually the truth is I'm putting a full screen button only on non full screen state.
I've tried the escape button listener too and it works great ! but this is okay as long as people leave full screen mode by the escape key.. what if they did through any other method? the "Leaving Full Screen" function won't trigger and won't show the return to full screen button!
Thanks so much though for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, backtoresize);
```

Comment: Tried it and gave the error:
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: event.